# Label unlabeled Karnaugh map according to given truth table

Tags: boolean-algebra

Assuming I have an unlabeled but filled out Karnaugh map and a truth table with variables, what algorithm can I follow to find the correct label (variable) for each row and column of the map?

**Example:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not always possible to assign the correct labels.

Example:

```
             cd
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
ab    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

Here, one could exchange `ab` and `cd` without changing the map.
This is the case for all symmetric maps (see below).

Imagine a map with all zero values or all one values. Again, it would not be possible to be certain about the labels.

Assuming a 4-input map with the order of rows and columns fixed to `00 01 11 10`, the four variables can be assigned in `4*3*2*1 = 24` ways. To determine a correct labeling, one could try them out starting with the most likely ones: `ab|cd`, `cd|ab`, `ac|bd`, `db|ca`.

The design principle of Karnaugh maps does enforce an ordering of rows and columns with exactly one bit-change between neighbors. Therefore, `00 10 11 01` or `11 10 00 01` would also be valid orderings. Taking this into account would lengthen the try-and-error search considerably.

In case the Karnaugh map is filled in a symmetric fashion (cell values do not change by swapping rows and columns), the number of label assignments is halved to `2*3*2*1 = 12`.

---

**Update:**

In your example, you could label the Karnaugh map with `vw` on the left and `xy` at the top. If you then derive a minimized expression for the Karnaugh map, you get

$$w\bar{y} \lor \bar{w} \bar{x} $$

From the truth table, you get:

$$\bar{c}d \lor \bar{a} \bar{d}$$

A comparison of these two expressions leads to the conclusion that:

- Label $w$ should be $d$
- Label $x$ should be $a$
- Label $y$ should be $c$
- Label $v$ should be $b$

Comment: The variables should be guaranteed to be assignable. Checking for symmetry seems a good way to cut the number of possible solutions that need to be checked (this is a possible exam question for me; I am given a map an need to label it, using as little time as possible - [example](https://imgur.com/a/s3bjbZT)).